# How to use react hooks on react-native with react-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is App.js using react-navigation. There are two screens on it called HomeScreen and AddScreen.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import HomeScreen from './src/HomeScreen';
import AddScreen from './src/AddScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Add" component={AddScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And This is home Screen. There is a 'items' in 'useState. It is gived through Add by navigation as props.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';


function HomeScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.items) {
      // Post updated, do something with `route.params.post`
      // For example, send the post to the server
      console.log('saved');
    }
  }, [route.params?.items]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Create post"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Add', { items, setItems })}
      />
      <View>
        {items.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.itemName}</Text>
              <Text>{item.itemPrice}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

HomeScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

And AddScreen receives 'items' as route.params. 
And it use 'setItems' to push his own data in it.
After adding, navigation return to HomeScreen with items that is added with new item.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

function AddScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const { items, setItems } = route.params;
  const [itemName, setItemName] = React.useState('');
  const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = React.useState('0');

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems([...items, { itemName, itemPrice }]);
    setItemName('');
    setItemPrice('0');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        value={itemName}
        onChangeText={setItemName}
      />
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        value={itemPrice}
        onChangeText={setItemPrice}
      />
      <Button
        title="Done"
        onPress={() => {
          addItem();
          // Pass params back to home screen
          navigation.navigate('Home', items);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

AddScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  route: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default AddScreen;
```

It works well on my purpose. 
But I'm not sure whether this way is correct or not using react hooks to give and receive data from parent to child.
Could you modify my code ?

Comment: You can simply create a function to addItems instead of passing the hook variables, will be less complex

Comment: @Guruparan Giritharan Can you write your code in an answer?

Comment: The answer below with the context implementation is recommended if you are going to access it from multiple screens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should consider using React Context API https://uk.reactjs.org/docs/context.html. Its dedicated to sharing the common state (`items` in your case). Here is an example:
You should create a common context for items:
ItemsState.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

const ItemsContext = React.createContext([]);

export const ItemsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <ItemsContext.Provider value={useState([])}>
      {children}
    </ItemsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useItems = () => useContext(ItemsContext);
```

Then share the context between screens with provider in App.js like this

```
import {ItemsProvider} from 'ItemsState';

function App() {
  return (
   <ItemsProvider> // share the items between both screens
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Add" component={AddScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
   </ItemsProvider>
  );
}
```

Then use items context in each screen like this AddScreen.js

```
import {useItems} from './ItemsState';

function AddScreen({ route, navigation }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useItems(); // <- using items context as global useState
  const [itemName, setItemName] = React.useState('');
  const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = React.useState('0');

  const addItem = () => {
    setItems([...items, { itemName, itemPrice }]);
    setItemName('');
    setItemPrice('0');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        value={itemName}
        onChangeText={setItemName}
      />
      <TextInput
        multiline
        placeholder="What's on your mind?"
        value={itemPrice}
        onChangeText={setItemPrice}
      />
      <Button
        title="Done"
        onPress={() => {
          addItem();
          // Pass params back to home screen
          navigation.navigate('Home', items);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can also use `useReducer` hook and make more Redux-like. Check out this article
https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c

Answer (score 0):

in order to share data between components you can use Context API or Redux, passing full objects through navigation routes is an anti-pattern, you can find more information in the docs

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/#what-should-be-in-params