# Warning: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my ReactHooks/Typescript app, I have a Navigation component, that renders a PatientInfo component. The PatientInfo child is rendered conditionally based on what props it is passed, as decided by a searchbox in another child component - MyPatients.

In this structure, I am getting the following error:

[image: et]

Navigation.tsx:

```
// code....
<Route exact path="/" component={MyPatients} />
<Route
    exact
    path="/Pasient"
    render={() => (
         <PatientInfo
              setName={setName}
              setSchema={setSchema}
              patientID={patientID}
          />
    )}
/>
// code....
```

MyPatients:

```
const MyPatients = (props: { history: History }) => {
    localStorage.clear();
    const [patientID, setPatientID] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem('myData') || '',
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('myData', patientID);
    }, [patientID]);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="search-container"></div>
            <Row gutter={[60, 40]} justify={'center'}>
                <Col span={1000}>
                    <p>Søk med personnummer for å finne en pasient</p>
                    <Search
                        style={{ width: 400 }}
                        className="search-bar"
                        placeholder="Søk etter en pasient!"
                        onSearch={(value: string) => setPatientID(value)}
                    />
                </Col>
            </Row>
            {patientID &&
                props.history.push({ pathname: 'Pasient', state: patientID })}
        </>
    );
};
export default MyPatients;
```

I am not familliar with this issue, and don't understand what's happening. My educated guess is that React doesn't like the fact that the state of the parent component is being updated by functions passed to the children, which again are dependant on the props passed along with it. Am I on to something? Any ideas as to what is causing this if not?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think the `props.history.push` should be in the effect

Comment: It is a bad idea to pass Navigation `setName` to child `PatientInfo`. You might get additional errors

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Hmr. however as stated in the below answer, the error persists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are navigating with `history.push` on each render.

As @HMR mentioned in the comment, you have to remove navigation from JSX template and add it into a separate effect.

```
const MyPatients = (props: { history: History }) => {
  localStorage.clear();
  const [patientID, setPatientID] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("myData") || ""
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("myData", patientID);
  }, [patientID]);

  // separate effect here
  useEffect(() => {
    if (patientID) {
      props.history.push({ pathname: "Pasient", state: patientID });
    }
  }, [props, patientID]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-container"></div>
      <Row gutter={[60, 40]} justify={"center"}>
        <Col span={1000}>
          <p>Søk med personnummer for å finne en pasient</p>
          <Search
            style={{ width: 400 }}
            className="search-bar"
            placeholder="Søk etter en pasient!"
            onSearch={(value: string) => setPatientID(value)}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};
export default MyPatients;
```

**EDIT**

This might cause your error:

```
<PatientInfo
  setName={setName}
  setSchema={setSchema}
  patientID={patientID}
/>
```

If you call `setName` or `setSchema` on render of `PatientInfo` then `Navigation` state gets *updated* before `PatientInfo` render is finished.

Comment: Ok, I understand. However, when making this change, it seems to load something incorrectly immediately, not letting me fill the searchfield. Im also getting  an instant 500 error from the server I am getting data from.

Comment: I figured it out. Adding the short-circuit to the new useeffect lets the app behave as it should 

(`useEffect(() => { patientID && props.history.push({ pathname: 'Pasient', state: patientID });  }, [props, patientID]); `)

Comment: ... but this is still giving me the error. any ideas?

Comment: I spoke too soon. The error is indeed there still. However, i dont really understand why. When writing the above comment, I was not getting the error - then suddenly now I am.

Comment: any ideas, @Rostyslav? I cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: That makes sense. The thing is, their respective statefields are used by other childre of Navigation, so state has to reside in Navigation. Do you have a suggestion for how I can circumvent the update-issue?

Comment: @MariusZ put your "statefields" in context [React Context API](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Checkout my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984106/how-to-use-react-hooks-on-react-native-with-react-navigation/61984321#61984321) It is for React-Native but context API is platform-agnostic.